# all functions that uphold $f'(x)=f(1/x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations

Find all functions $y:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that 
$$y'(x)=y\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big)$$
we can differentiate both sides to get a homogenous second order Euler equation
$$y''(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2}y'\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big)=-\frac{1}{x^2}y(x)\implies x^2y''+y=0$$
which is doable.

My question is, am I missing something? From a short glance at WA it doesn't seem that all of the solutions of the Euler equation uphold the required criteria.

Comment: How do you know that the second derivative exists?

Comment: @asdf: the first derivative is differentiable because it equals $y(1/x)$, which is differentiable by assumption.

Comment: Well, there is no obvious reason that a solution to $x^2y''+y=0$ must be a solution to the original equation; your steps are not reversible.

Comment: It doesn't seem right to consider the domain of $y$ to equal $\Bbb R$, since then $y'(0)$ isn't well-defined. Perhaps it makes more sense to have the domain be $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: What you have now is a family of solutions to $y'(x)=y\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big)\color{red}{+C}$.

Comment: You have derived a necessary condition (the second-order differential equation), to which you can find all solutions; then just check which of those solutions satisfy your original equation.

Comment: Related [Solving $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}_+^*, f'(x) = f\left(\frac1{x}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31492/solving-forall-x-in-mathbbr-fx-f-left-frac1x-right)

Comment: @EricWofsey. A solution to $x^2 y'' + y = 0$ doesn't have to be a solution to the original equation, but a solution to the original equation has to be a solution to this equation. Therefore, you can first solve this equation, and then from those solutions find which are also solutions to the first equation; there can be no other solutions.